# How can I show ad every three times when entering a screen in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a recipe details screen and I want to add an interstitial ad every time the user enters to see the recipe details, but I want to limit it to be shown every three times, because when the user exits and re-enters it, a recipe or another recipe shows the ad again and I don't want this.

How can I do this?

```
import { AdMobInterstitial, setTestDeviceIDAsync } from 'expo-ads-admob';

export default class RecipeDetails extends Component {

initAds = async () => {

const INTERSTITIAL_ID = Platform.OS == "ios" ? ConfigApp.IOS_INTERSTITIAL_ID : ConfigApp.ANDROID_INTERSTITIAL_ID;

AdMobInterstitial.setAdUnitID(INTERSTITIAL_ID);
await setTestDeviceIDAsync(ConfigApp.TESTDEVICE_ID);
await AdMobInterstitial.requestAdAsync({ servePersonalizedAds: true});
await AdMobInterstitial.showAdAsync();

};

componentDidMount() {

     this.initAds();

   }

render() {

  return (
<View>
// content
</View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [async-storage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage) to store times every time when you called ads. And read every times you have stored to compare if it equals three before playing ads?

Store data(times)

```
storeData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', 'stored value')//
  } catch (e) {
    // saving error
  }
}
```

Read data(times)

```
getData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
    if(value !== null) {
      // value previously stored
    }
  } catch(e) {
    // error reading value
  }
}
```

--------------update----------------Something you want like this-------

```
initAds = async () => {

  const INTERSTITIAL_ID = Platform.OS == "ios" ? ConfigApp.IOS_INTERSTITIAL_ID : ConfigApp.ANDROID_INTERSTITIAL_ID;
  try{
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('play_ad_times')
      if(value !== null) {
          if(value == "3"){ 
             await AsyncStorage.setItem('play_ad_times', "1"); //If three times back to one times and play once

             AdMobInterstitial.setAdUnitID(INTERSTITIAL_ID);
             await setTestDeviceIDAsync(ConfigApp.TESTDEVICE_ID);
             await AdMobInterstitial.requestAdAsync({ servePersonalizedAds: true});
             await AdMobInterstitial.showAdAsync();

          }else{
             var temp = parseInt(value)+1;
             await AsyncStorage.setItem('play_ad_times', temp.toString() );
          }
      // value previously stored
      }else{
          //first time in
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('play_ad_times', "1"); //Set time 1
          AdMobInterstitial.setAdUnitID(INTERSTITIAL_ID);
          await setTestDeviceIDAsync(ConfigApp.TESTDEVICE_ID);
          await AdMobInterstitial.requestAdAsync({ servePersonalizedAds: true});
          await AdMobInterstitial.showAdAsync();


          }
      }catch(e) {
        // error reading value
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('play_ad_times', "1");
      }

};
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211788/discussion-on-answer-by--how-can-i-show-ad-every-3-times-entering-a-screen-in).